# Google app engine PHP file upload "vfs://root/uploads/0"

Tags: php, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-drive-api

I have a project, deployed on the google App Engine.

I want to upload files to Google drive.

I am using a form with `enctype=multipart/form-data`

Where the user can select a file to upload with the input:

```
<input type='file' name='fileToUpload' >
```

after the submit - `$_FILES` looks like this:

```
array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(44) "Noordzee zit weer vol vis - De Standaard.pdf" ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf" ["tmp_name"]=> string(20) "vfs://root/uploads/0" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(654999) } }
```

Especially `["tmp_name"]=> string(20) "vfs://root/uploads/0"` is a bit disappointing, it doesn’t look like a temp file on the server...

If I want to read the temp-file contents in php:

```
$data = file_get_contents( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] );
```

this is the result:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "vfs" - did
>   you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in
>   /base/data/home/apps/xxxxxx/UploadFile.php on line 38  Warning:
>   file_get_contents(vfs://root/uploads/0): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in /base/data/home/apps/xxxxxxxx/

I use a php.ini and I think the problem has to do with the php configuaration on the server.

I want to read the 'fileToUpload' files data, insert a file in google drive and write the read content to the inserted file on drive.

This comes down to uploading a file to google drive.

Can someone please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?